# Can Artifactory utilize Oracle RAC? If yes, then what Oracle Versions and Editions are supported?

Tags: oracle, artifactory

We are Installing Artifactory on Oracle and would like to know if it support Oracle RAC?
If yes, then what Oracle Versions and Editions are supported?

Answer (score 1):

As it seems, Artifactory supports only Oracle DB (from version 10g and above), but not RAC. For more information on supported DBs you can review JFrog's wiki page on [Supported Databases](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+the+Database)

Comment: Thank you Yonatan for your answers, but unfortunately it does not answer my questions concerning Oracle Editions.